# Is randomness in the collapse of the wavefunction in quantum mechanics simply a manifestation of chaos, and not inherently random at all?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, gravity, quantum-information, quantum-gravity

Chaos is sensitivity to initial conditions.  Could the randomness in quantum mechanics simply be a manifestation of chaos?? The initial conditions would be both the initial state of a particle, and perhaps initial conditions of the measurement device at the time of measurement, and in the fields present at the particle location at the time of measurement. Roger Penrose believes gravity plays a role in the collapse of the wavefunction, so gravity could be included here (in factoring in of initial conditions).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Bell's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem), which have been experimentally tested show that there is no local hidden variable theory that can reproduce the results of quantum mechanics (modulo some small loopholes). What this means is that a classical theory in the normal sense simply cannot reproduce quantum mechanics. Whether or not the classical theory is chaotic is irrelevant. There has to be *something* strange going on. The mainstream view is that the "something" is that the world is quantum, and not deterministic.

Comment: I recognize there is a mainstream view.  However, a few prominent physicists believe things are not inherently random at the core.  I am simply asking for what is possible given current experimental observations.

Comment: Chaos is not a solution to the problem, because chaos is a feature of classical mechanics. Classical mechanics is not able to reproduce the results of Bell's inequality tests. To explain observations while avoiding standard quantum mechanics, you have to change classical mechanics in a deep way, such as making it nonlocal (which is hard to jive with special relativity because in special relativity nonlocality implies acausal transfer of information, meaning you can kill your grandfather), or by appealing to [superdeterminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdeterminism).

Comment: I do like your above comment, but I guess I would like some more specific rigorous reasons for that. Also appreciate the link.

Comment: Bell's inequalities are the rigorous statement. Both the mathematical proof and experimental tests are described in the wikipedia article about Bell's inequalities I linked above.

Comment: I know about Bell's inequalities.  I think what I'm wondering might connected to "objective-collapse theories" where the collapse of the wavefunction happens as a result of connecting the macroscopic to the microscopic (and as a result, according to my understanding, could in theory be predicted).

Comment: I guess one could say that the wavefunction is itself the hidden variable, and measurement by a macroscopic being would collapse it in a deterministic way to what we call a "measurement".

Comment: (Deterministic but indeterminate, in that it would near impossible to predict the result for a macroscopic being making a measurement)

Comment: There are many researchers that think that way, and there have been some advances into this. I believe that ultimately, we will find out this to be the case. It has to include some kind of wormhole-like connections if we still want to keep it "local", so a measurement far aways can still mess up a particle that is entangled with it. This is more an opinion than an answer, that is why I post it as a comment.

Comment: We. Don't. Know.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Even if one can reproduce exactly the initial state and the measurements are ideal (thus even if the initial conditions are exactly identical) the outcomes can be randomly different.

Thus, even if multiple copies of a system are exactly prepared so the initial state is the spin-up state along $+\hat z$ $\vert +;z\rangle$ (exactly same initial conditions on all copies) and the copies are fed in identical copies of a perfect apparatus designed to measure the $\hat y$ component of spin, the outcome of any *one* measurement would have 50/50 chance of being either $\vert +;y\rangle$ or $\vert -;y\rangle$.

Comment: @CarlosGauss Not sure I follow.  There is no interpretation here; the interpretation comes *after*, in explaining the (possibly apparent) randomness, not in the factual observation that the outcomes are 50/50.

Comment: @CarlosGauss I am not suggesting an *explanation* to this randomness (real or apparent), just claiming it is random inasmuch as identical preparation and perfect measurement do not lead to identical outcomes (hence independence on initial conditions).

Comment: @CarlosGauss I edited my answer to hopefully remove some confusion.

Comment: I see, thanks, I am sorry about the confusion, I erased my comment

Comment: I guess my comment is that perhaps the initial states of all the atoms in the measurement apparatus, and the initial state of all the fields (including perhaps gravitational) could not be exactly reproduced in practice, and hence the apparent randomness.  These are the “initial conditions” I was referring to.

Comment: @JosephRobertJepson you can guarantee initial conditions to arbitrary precision.

Comment: I’m not sure about that.  In an idealized measurement device, maybe, but in practice (with an actual measurement device in a laboratory), is it possible?  For what I’m arguing here, one would need to make sure the combined wave function of the macroscopic apparatus (which includes Avogadro’s number worth of atoms) would need to be exactly reproduced.

Comment: well you are incorrect.  Randomness in quantum mechanics is not something that is tied to the measuring device or the initial conditions.  *Calculations* where you assume these are perfect still yield random distributions.

Comment: Yes.  But calculations are no good unless verified experimentally.  I am arguing for an apparent randomness which arises from a connection of the microscopic with the macroscopic.

Comment: clearly no argument will satisfy you so there is really nothing more to add.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents of the euro, you ask:

> Is randomness in the collapse of the wavefunction in quantum mechanics simply a manifestation of chaos, and not inherently random at all?

Do an experiment with a dice.After 1000 throws there is a distribution with the number of times the six faces came up. If it you get a flat probability distribution you decide on true randomness of classical mechanics probable  motions on the dice. If you see a biased distribution, you attribute it to a weighted dice.

The experiments at the quantum level do not show, cannot be modeled with classical mechanics statistical distributions. We attribute the bias to quantum mechanics which by now is an elaborate mathematical model , that fits the distributions and, important , predicts correctly new ones. And the collapse is not random in the  theory, it is biased with the wavefunction distribution ($Ψ^*Ψ$)

My point is that the "collapse" is biased, not random according to mainstream theory.  Chaos would produce random distributions, but the data, [crossections](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/hadronic-xsections/) and decays directly connected to the probability distribution  are not random.

Comment: Is it true that chaos cannot produced biased distributions?? If you could add more explanation to your answer that would be helpful.

Comment: a specialist in chaos should answer that. It is a different question.,